# No me aparece la libreria SQL en mi netbeans para usar

Tags: java, netbeans, mysqlconnector.jar

Me surgió una duda y problema.

Estoy intentando hacer una conexión a base de datos con MySQL.
Descargué la librería del conector,[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de ingresarla al proyecto no me aparece para su uso.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me sale la siguiente libreria pero desconozco si es esa la que tengo que usar o si hice algun paso mal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte donde la agregaste.

Comment: La añadí a la carpeta Libraries solo que la manda hasta abajo, ya añadí la imagen a la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está agregada de forma correcta, sólo debes incluir al inicio de tu clase o enseguida de `package clases;` la siguiente línea de código:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
```

Con esto ya podrás hacer lo que buscas.
En seguida de esto, te reconocerá la importación de la librería y podrás ir agregando según las clases que te solicite el código.

Comment: copié esa misma linea que me comentas, pero me aparece como "cannot find symbol"

Comment: olvidalo, no se como, pero ya aceptó la linea de codigo, gracias

Comment: No hay cuidado.